# How to save and retrieve "Dimension" from SQLite

Tags: swift, sqlite

Can someone help me figure out how to save and retrieve a `Dimension` from SQLite in Swift? `Dimension` conforms to `NSSecureCoding` so i figure i should be able to serialize it.

Here's where I'm saving the Dimension (appears to be working)

```
func add(value: Int, unit: Dimension) throws -> SQLMeasurement {
    let insertSql = "INSERT INTO Measurements (value, unit) VALUES (?,?);"
    let insertStatement = try database.prepareStatement(sql: insertSql)
    guard sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 1, Int32(value)) == SQLITE_OK else { fatalError() }
    guard let dimensionData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: unit, requiringSecureCoding: false) else { fatalError() }
    print(dimensionData.base64EncodedString())
    let bindResult = sqlite3_bind_blob(insertStatement, 2, dimensionData.base64EncodedString(), Int32(dimensionData.count), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
    let result = sqlite3_step(insertStatement)
    let lastId = database.lastId()
    sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement)
    return SQLMeasurement(id: lastId, db: database)
}
```

Here's where I'm to extract it. (Failing with Error Code:)

```
func unit() -> Dimension {
    let sql = "SELECT unit FROM Measurements WHERE id = ?"
    let queryStatement = try! db.prepareStatement(sql: sql) //TODO: Remove Bang!
    guard sqlite3_bind_int(queryStatement, 1, Int32(id)) == SQLITE_OK else { fatalError() }
    guard sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW else { fatalError() }
    guard let dataBlob = sqlite3_column_blob(queryStatement, 0) else { fatalError() }
    let dataBlobLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(queryStatement, 0)
    let data = Data(bytes: dataBlob, count: Int(dataBlobLength))
    do {
        let result = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: Dimension.self, from: data)
        return result!
    }
    catch { print("unarchive error: \(error)") }
    //let dimension2 = dimension(data: data)
    sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
    return UnitPower.kilowatts //FIXME:
}
```

Here's the error code from the unarchive request:

```
unarchive error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: incomprehensible archive version (-1)" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: incomprehensible archive version (-1)}
```

Here's the Error on unarchive:

[image]

Here's the sqlite database confirming the save as working:

[image]

This playground works:

```
import UIKit

func dimension4(string64: String) -> Dimension {
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: string64) else { fatalError() }
    guard let dimension2 = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? Dimension else { fatalError() }
    return dimension2
}

func dimension(data: Data) -> Dimension {
    guard let dimension2 = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? Dimension else { fatalError() }
    return dimension2
}

let dimension = UnitMass.grams

guard let dimensionData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dimension, requiringSecureCoding: false) else { fatalError() }
let dimensionFromData = dimension(data: dimensionData)
print("dimensionFromData: \(dimensionFromData.description)")

let stringData = dimensionData.base64EncodedString()
let dimensionFromString64 = dimension4(string64: stringData)
print("dimensionFromString64: \(dimensionFromString64.description)")
```

FINAL ANSWER

```
import Foundation
import SQLite3

class SQLMeasurements
{
    let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)  //FIXME: Why do i need this to work?

    private let database: SQLiteDatabase
    var index: Int = 1 //SQL indexes start at 1...TODO: violating the mutability principle

    init(database: SQLiteDatabase) {
        self.database = database
        let sql = """
        CREATE TABLE Measurements(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            value Number(6) NOT NULL,
            unit BLOB NOT NULL
        );
        """
        do { try database.createTable(sql: sql) }
        catch { print(database.errorMessage) }
    }

    func add(value: Int, unit: Dimension) throws -> SQLMeasurement {
        let sql = "INSERT INTO Measurements (value, unit) VALUES (?,?);"
        let insertStatement = try database.prepareStatement(sql: sql)
        defer { sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement) } //Free Memory
        guard sqlite3_bind_int(insertStatement, 1, Int32(value)) == SQLITE_OK else { fatalError() }
        guard let dimensionData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: unit, requiringSecureCoding: false) else { fatalError() }
        let rc = dimensionData.withUnsafeBytes {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(insertStatement, 2, $0.baseAddress, Int32(dimensionData.count), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
        }
        guard rc == SQLITE_OK else { fatalError() }
        guard sqlite3_step(insertStatement) == SQLITE_DONE else { fatalError() }
        let lastId = database.lastId()
        return SQLMeasurement(id: lastId, db: database)
    }
```

///

```
import Foundation
import SQLite3

class SQLMeasurement
{
    private let db: SQLiteDatabase
    let id: Int

    init(id: Int, db: SQLiteDatabase) {    //FIXME: Construct w value and unit
        self.db = db
        self.id = id
    }

    func value() -> Int {
        let sql = "SELECT value FROM Measurements WHERE id = ?"
        let queryStatement = try! db.prepareStatement(sql: sql) //TODO: Remove Bang!
        guard sqlite3_bind_int(queryStatement, 1, Int32(id)) == SQLITE_OK else { fatalError() }
        guard sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW else { fatalError() }
        let queryResultCol1 = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
        sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement)
        return Int(queryResultCol1)
    }

    func unit() -> Dimension {
        let sql = "SELECT unit FROM Measurements WHERE id = ?"
        guard let queryStatement = try? db.prepareStatement(sql: sql) else { fatalError() }
        defer { sqlite3_finalize(queryStatement) }
        guard sqlite3_bind_int(queryStatement, 1, Int32(id)) == SQLITE_OK else { fatalError() }
        guard sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW else { fatalError() }
        guard let dataBlob = sqlite3_column_blob(queryStatement, 0) else { fatalError() }
        let dataBlobLength = sqlite3_column_bytes(queryStatement, 0)
        let data = Data(bytes: dataBlob, count: Int(dataBlobLength))
        guard let unit = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: Dimension.self, from: data) else { fatalError() }
        return unit
    }`
```

////

```
import XCTest
@testable import FitWrench

class MeasurementsTests: XCTestCase
{
    var measurements: SQLMeasurements!

    override func setUp() {
        let db = SQLiteDatabase()
        self.measurements = SQLMeasurements(database: db)
    }
    override func tearDown() { }

    func testAddMeasurement() {
        do {
            let measurement = try measurements.add(value: 90, unit: UnitPower.watts)
            XCTAssertEqual(measurement.value(), 90)
            XCTAssertEqual(measurement.unit(), UnitPower.watts)
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            XCTFail()
        }
    }

    func testRemoveMeasurement() { XCTAssertEqual(99, 100) }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

1. Binding:

   The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) tells us:

   > If the fourth parameter to `sqlite3_bind_blob()` is negative, then the behavior is undefined.

   In your original version of your question (which you’ve now changed), use used -1 for this fourth parameter. You should use `dimensionData.count` for that fourth parameter. Unlike when handling strings, in the absence of the byte count, `sqlite3_bind_blob()` has no way of knowing how much binary data there is.

   Also note that the third parameter of `sqlite3_bind_blob()` should be the `dimensionData` itself, not a base64 representation of it. For example, use `withUnsafeBytes` to get the `baseAddress` which we can supply to `sqlite3_bind_blob`:

   ```
   let rc = dimensionData.withUnsafeBytes {
       sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, $0.baseAddress, Int32(dimensionData.count), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
   }
   guard rc == SQLITE_OK else {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Retrieving:

   The `sqlite3_column_blob` and `sqlite3_column_bytes` are both using an index of 2. That should be 0 because the BLOB is the first column in the result set (and because, unlike the bind `sqlite3_bind_xxx` API, the `sqlite3_column_xxx` functions use a 0-based index). As [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) says:

   > The leftmost column of the result set has the index 0.
3. Unarchiving:

   To unarchive, you unarchive from the `data` directly:

   ```
   let result = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: Dimension.self, from: data)
   ```

Comment: That worked for the first part of the question Rob, thank you. Any advice on how to unarchive the Data and convert it back into a "Dimension"

Comment: updated to the latest code. also included a playground that works for two cases of decoding from a base64 string and from a Data object. i'm getting an error when i go to unarchive the data error code 4864. any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you’re storing a base64 string of the archive. Just store the `Data` from the archive itself. That’s why we use blobs, so we can save the `Data` directly.

Comment: yeah that makes sense.

Comment: the compiler doesn't like it when i just pass in a dimensionData to the `sqlite3_bind_blob(insertStatement, 2, dimensionData, Int32(dimensionData.count), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)`

Comment: The compiler doesn't mind when i pass it a `String` but it crashes at runtime.

Comment: This is crashing `guard let dataAsString = String(data: dimensionData, encoding: .utf8) else { fatalError() }`

Comment: How do i convert the data to a swift string?

Comment: The whole idea of blobs is to _not_ use a string. That’s inefficient. The real question is “how do I pass `Data` to `sqlite3_bind_blob`?” Use `withUnsafeBytes` to get a pointer to the buffer for a `Data`.

Comment: i understand what your saying. would you show me how to do that? `withUnsafeBytes` is deprecated.

Comment: No, there are two `withUnsafeBytes`. [The one with `UnsafePointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes) is deprecated. [The other with `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3139154-withunsafebytes) is not. Did you try the syntax I showed in my answer, in which I refer to `baseAddress` (which resolves the compiler’s ambiguity about which rendition of `withUnsafeBytes` to use)?

Comment: If you feel compelled to use a string, then (a) archive the `Dimension` into a`Data`; (b) base64 encode it; (c) store with `sqlite3_bind_text` (with length of -1) not `sqlite3_bind_blob` (with length of `data.count`); (d) retrieve with `sqlite_column_text` not `sqlite3_column_blob`; (e) base 64 decode it; (f) unarchive it. I wouldn’t advise it (it’s unnecessarily adding two extra steps; making the storage for the `Dimension` data 33% bigger than it needs to be; etc), but you can do it.